# Python async - all aiohttp request get sent at once

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Im working with python 3.7 and [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp), trying to send async http requests from a client to a server.
This is the server code:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web


async def hello(request):
    print('Got request')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    headers = {"content_type": "text/html"}
    response = web.Response(body='Hello', headers=headers)
    return response

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_route("GET", "/", hello)
web.run_app(app)
```

and this is the client code:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import time


async def fetch(url, session):
    print('Starting request')
    # some blocking calculation
    time.sleep(0.3)
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        print('Finished request')


async def run(r):
    url = "http://localhost:8080"
    tasks = []
    start = time.time()
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(r):
            task = asyncio.create_task(fetch(url, session))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print(time.time()-start)

asyncio.run(run(10))
```

However I have an issue where it looks like all of the requests are being 'prepared' one at a time but then sent all at once.

This is how the output is printed where the "blocking calculation" is inside of the for "fetch" func: [gif1](https://giant.gfycat.com/FantasticMarvelousJaeger.webm)

And this is how it looks where the "blocking calculation" is done inside of the for loop: [gif2](https://giant.gfycat.com/FrighteningSafeChinesecrocodilelizard.webm)

I have two questions.
1. What causes this difference in behaviour between gif1 and 2?
2. Why do all the requests get send at once? I Would excpected a output similat to this:

Starting request
Starting request
Starting request
Finished request
Finished request
Starting request
Finished request
...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that blocking code such as a call to `time.sleep(0.3)` cannot be executed in parallel by asyncio because it blocks the whole event loop thread. Replace it with [`await asyncio.sleep(0.3)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) and the issue will go away.

If you have actual blocking code that you must run inside the coroutine (e.g. a numpy computation), use [`await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_function)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to run the calculation in a side thread and safely await the result, allowing other coroutines to make progress while waiting.

Comment: But what progress do other coroutines need to do? I would like to send the http request and only then release control of the coroutine. The "progress" is just waiting for the server to answer after 2 seconds

Comment: @RonSerruya For one, the progress is actually getting to start execute any of them. Note how in `gif1` you have 0.3s pauses between "Start requests" printouts - that is because each coroutine blocks the event loop before starting to execute the next one. `time.sleep()` is not an asyncio function so it doesn't suspend the coroutine, nor does it allow asyncio to be aware of the sleep and parallelize the sleeps into a single one. Since the coroutines are effectively executing in series, they are also sending their requests in series.

Comment: The other thing is, the event loop itself has to get a chance to run to pick up the data, which won't happen if it is stuck in `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Ok, so I have a client that needs to do a blocking calculation, send the request to a server which will return the answer after a few seconds. While I'm waiting for the answer I want to calculate more stuff and send more requests. Would I need to put all of the calculation in ```run_in_excecutor```? I mean, ```print``` and ```append``` are not async but they are still fine? @user4815162342

Comment: @RonSerruya Yes, anything that can take considerable time should be off-loaded to a thread/process pool with `run_in_executor`. What constitutes _considerable time_ is not precisely defined, but it is generally understood that "trivial" stuff like `append` is safe to execute immediately. Use your discretion and treat your coroutine the way you would treat a Twisted (or other async framework's) callback. If some sync operation doesn't look like it belongs in an async callback, wrap it in `run_in_executor` - or refactor it to be async, such as when changing `time.sleep` to `asyncio.sleep`.